# QVector with custom objects that have arguments?

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qvector

I`m trying to use a QVector with a custom object named RoutineItem.

But this error is given:

```
C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include\QtCore\qvector.h:265: error: no matching function for call to 'RoutineItem::RoutineItem()'
```

This is the RoutineItem constructor:

```
RoutineItem(QString Name,int Position,int Time,bool hasCountdown = false,bool fastNext = false);
```

If I remove all the constructor arguments I no longer get that error.
How can I use QVector with a custom object that has arguments?

Comment: As with standard containers you'll need to provide a default constructible type for QVector.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The C++11 standard containers do not require default-constructible items. The requirements places on the items are specific to how you use the container. For example, `std::list` doesn't even require copy-constructible items if you can stick to the `emplace_` instead of `push_` methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No matching call to default constructor, when using QVector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181249/no-matching-call-to-default-constructor-when-using-qvector)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that QVector requires that the element has a default constructor (that is the error message about). You can define one in your class. For example:

```
class RoutineItem {
    RoutineItem(QString Name, int Position,
                int Time, bool hasCountdown = false,
                bool fastNext = false);
    RoutineItem();
    [..]
};
```

Alternatively, you can let all arguments have a default values:

```
class RoutineItem {
    RoutineItem(QString Name = QString(), int Position = 0,
                int Time = 0, bool hasCountdown = false,
                bool fastNext = false);
    [..]
};
```

Alternatively, you can construct a default value of RoutineItem and initialize all vector items by it:

```
RoutineItem item("Item", 0, 0);
// Create a vector of 10 elements and initialize them with `item` value
QVector<RoutineItem> vector(10, item);
```

Answer (score 2):

Provide the non-default arguments in [*QVector constructor*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvector.html#QVector-3)

Example: following creates 10 `RoutineItem` elements with same `Name`, `Position`, `Time`

```
QVector<RoutineItem> foo(10, RoutineItem("name", 123, 100 ));
                                            ^     ^     ^
                                            |     |     |
                                            +-----+-----+-----Provide arguments
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use C++11 and `std::vector`, there's no more requirement for default-constructability:

```
void test()
{
   class C {
   public:
      explicit C(int) {}
   };

   std::vector<C> v;
   v.push_back(C(1));
   v.push_back(C(2));
}
```

This code won't work pre-C++11, and it won't work with `QVector`.