# No matching call to default constructor, when using QVector

Tags: c++, qt, qvector

I have a class B that creates an object of a class A and calls a method of the object.

a.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A
{
public:
    A(int);
    void function();
};

#endif // A_H
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

A::A(int x)
{

}
void A::function(){
    //Do something.
}
```

b.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
#include <QVector>
#include <a.h>


class B
{
public:
    B(int);
    QVector<A> list;
};

#endif // B_H
```

b.cpp

```
#include "b.h"

B::B(int y)
{
    list.append(A(y));
    list[0].function();
}
```

The problem is that this does not compile. It returns "no matching function to call 'A:A()'". I know that this can be solved with a forward declaration but this does not work here since I want to call the function "function". I also do not want to include the whole class A in the class B.

Comment: Looks like Qt's asking for a default constructor.

Comment: your interpretation is not quite correct.  "no matching function to call 'A:A()'" means that `A` has no default constructor, but you are trying to call it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As with many Qt containers, [`QVector`'s element type must be an *assignable data type*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#details) in your version.

Unlike the standard library, [Qt defines this as](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#assignable-data-type):

> The values stored in the various containers can be of any assignable data type. To qualify, a type must provide a default constructor, a copy constructor, and an assignment operator.

This is really unfortunate, because [there's no practical need for a default constructor in your example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33380402/560648), and indeed a `std::vector` would (compliantly) let you use an element type that doesn't have one.

The `QVector::value(int)` function does rely on this property, but you're not using it! The Qt devs must be doing some kind of checks up-front, rather than taking the standard library's approach of "just check preconditions when they're actually needed", or else this is an "accident" of the code!

As a consequence, [until 5.13 in which this was changed](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/?id=01301b0b340df736dd1b0a54b3026e00b49c5ea3), **you will have to give `A` a default constructor**, sorry.

Don't forget a copy constructor, too… and a proper qualification on that `A::function()` definition.

A forward declaration will not solve this, neither do you need one. In fact, adding one to this particular program will do literally nothing. ;)

Comment: The alternative solution is to switch to `std::vector` of course.

Comment: Good News Everyone! The requirement of a default constructor for QVector has been finally dropped in 5.13 ([commit](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/?id=01301b0b340df736dd1b0a54b3026e00b49c5ea3)).

Comment: *The Qt devs must be doing some kind of checks up-front, rather than taking the standard library's approach of "just check preconditions when they're actually needed".* It's worse... it's just sloppy coding, e.g. calling `resize()` from insertion functions or stuff like that :-(

Comment: @peppe: Possibly. Possibly not. (Ignore if you literally know otherwise from the source!)

Comment: Gory details: in 5.12 `detach()` (called by any non-const function, e.g. insertion functions) calls into `reallocData()`, which is a one-size-fits-all function that does detaching, allocation, resizing, reserving, and so on. The result is the imposed requirement. Other functions are also sloppy coded (e.g. `clear()` in 5.12 calls `resize(0)`).

Answer (score 0):

First in `a.cpp` update function definition:

```
void A::function(){  // A: added
    //Do something.
}
```

Second, I would add `A(const A&)` copy constructor since list may need this for internal buffer reallocation purposes.

Comment: While you're right that the `function` definition is currently broken, and that a copy constructor should be added, none of this answers the question, which is about why a default-constructor is being invoked and how best to resolve that.